# cancel Ajax request on new emmision in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I am new to reactive programming and having an issue in creating an AJAX navigation side navigation.

```
<ul>
    <li>change_password</li>
    <li>update_profile</li>
</ul>
<h3> The result </h3>
<div id="theContent"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var listClick$ = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){

            $('li').click(function(){

                let pageName = $(this).html();    
                observer.next(pageName);

            });

        }).startWith('change_password').flatMap(function(pageName){

            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/settings/'+pageName));        
        });
listClick$.subscribe(function(gottenJson){

$('#theContent').html(gottenJson.page);
}); 
</script>
```

When i click on change_password or update_profile, an ajax request is made but that of change_password is delayed, so when it is clicked and then update_profile is clicked, update_profile form is displayed but is then replaced by change_password form when it is complete.

How will i be able to cancel the first AJAX request when another list item is clicked?

Comment: i've been able to prevent the previous emission from replacing the latest by changing `flatMap` to `flatMapLatest` . but the AJAX request still goes on.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the `Rx.Observable.fromEvent` constructor to simplify your code

Comment: Yeah.I'll replace the `create` with `fromEvent`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `switchMap` which unsubscribes from the previous stream (your Ajax call) when a new emission is generated.

That being said; because you use a promise Ajax version there is no way to cancel that request. So even though that switchMap provides the hook for cancellation (`unsubscribe`) the promise will not act upon that.

You can use [`Rx.Observable.ajax`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js.html) for an Observable version. This call is able to be aborted when you unsubscribe before it has completed. AFAIK it relies on DOM so in a nodejs environment you can use the [universal Ajax npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-rxjs-ajax) which replaces the internal `xhr` with `xhr2` from npm when running  in a non-DOM env.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I figured out the `switchMap` part. Will check on `Rx.Observable.ajax`. Thats what i actually need!